# Func with interface argument not equals to func with string argument. Why?

Tags: go

I cant understand whats the problem.
Here is sample code:

```go
type InterfaceFunction func(i interface{})
func main() {
    var notOk InterfaceFunction = func(s string){}
    var ok InterfaceFunction = func(i interface{}){}
}
```

Comment: Because they're not the same thing.

Comment: `interface{}` does **not** mean "any type"; it means just `interface{}`.

Comment: @Volker But when we call fmt.Println("1234", 1234) there is no problems

Comment: At runtime, `interface{}` will accept any type like `int` or `string`. But as a type _definition_,  `interface{}` does not match/equal `string`.

Comment: There is a major difference between "being" and "can assign to". `interface{}` is just `interface{}` it is neither `int` nor `string` nor whatever. But you can _asign_ any value of any type to a variable of type `interface{}`. Just because something is assignable does not mean it is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the types aren't the same. Imagine this:

```
type InterfaceFunction func(i interface{})

func main() {
    var notOk InterfaceFunction = func(s string){}
    myFunc(InterfaceFunction(notOk))    // This can't possibly work!
}

func myFunc(fn InterfaceFunction) {
    x := 17
    fn(x)   // This is legal, because InterfaceFunction takes an interface{}
}
```

Our `myFunc` here takes an `InterfaceFunction`, which, *by definition*, takes any `interface{}` as its argument. `myFunc` can pass it anything it wants. If we were allowed to use a `func(string)` as a `func(interface{})` here, `myFunc` would no longer have compile-time type-safety: it would be passing an `int` to a function that takes a `string`.